# how to create namespaces and classes in javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just like C# or Java to put all my jQuery code in one .js file, something like this:

```
namespace MySite
{
    class HomePage
    {
        function Init(params) { /*...*/ }
        //...
    }

    class ContactForm
    {
        function Validate() { /*...*/ }
        //...
    }
}
```

So you can call it in this way:

```
$(function () {
    MySite.HomePage.Init({a : "msg"});
});
```

I have this code, but doesn't work:

```
$.namespace = function () {
    var a = arguments, o = null, i, j, d;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i = i + 1) {
        d = a[i].split(".");
        o = window;
        for (j = 0; j < d.length; j = j + 1) {
            o[d[j]] = o[d[j]] || {};
            o = o[d[j]];
        }
    }
    return o;
};

$.namespace('$.mysite');

$.mysite.Home = function () {

    function Home(params) {
        //...
    };

    Home.prototype = function () {
        Init: function () {
            alert("lol");
        }
    }
};
```

Is it possible to that in jQuery? (something similar or recommendations / examples to keep my jquery code organized. )
Thanks for your time and answers (sorry for my bad english).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just put it inside a js object?

```
var _o = {};
_o.module1 = {};
_o.module2 = {};

_o.module1.someFunc = function(){//code};
_o.module2.someFunc = function(){//code};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var MODULE = (function () {
     var my = {},
     privateVariable = 1;

     function privateMethod() {
     // ...     
     }
     my.moduleProperty = 1;
     my.moduleMethod = function () {
     // ...     
     };
     return my;
     }());
```

If I understood well, you want to add your namespace under jQuery. To do that you need to use technique called *sub moduling*;

```
MODULE.sub = (function () {
     var my = {};
     // ...
     return my;
 }());
```

Or, you can use *module import*:

```
(function(jQuery){
    jQuery.myNamespace = {};
    jQuery.myNamespace.myFunc = function(arg){
        console.log(arg);
    };
}($));
```

After that you can run it like this:

```
$.myNamespace.myFunc("somevalue")
```

And it will write:

```
LOG: raera
```

For more techniques and examples, see http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

Answer (score 0):

```
var nameSpace= {};
nameSpace.nameSpace1= nameSpace.nameSpace1|| (function()
   {
   }());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MySite = {
    HomePage : {
        Init: function(params) { /*...*/ }
    },
    ContactForm: {
        Validate: function() { /*...*/ }
    }
};
```